# Damped Track constraint issues. Bone twists at a certain point

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

Having issues with the damped track constraint here. I want to be able to move it all the way around and have the arm follow it. However, at a certain point, this weird rotation thing happens.

I don't even know where to start

Hopefully someone can help

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use IK constraint with chain lenght of 1, instead of damped track constraint. When selecting the Ikeyed bone, in its IK properties panel lock the axes in which you don't want any rotation.

[image]

Comment: Hi, this worked thanks, however, I still want to be able to pull the arm out of the lego socket. Locking the rotation axis prevents this

Comment: You can unlock the needed rotation axis (in my example X).